# How to get data from a JSON request and display in metro app

Tags: c#, json, parsing, microsoft-metro

I have a URL that has this JSON data:

```
[{"title":"Snow White & the Huntsman","year":2012,"released":1338534000,"url":"http://localhost/movie/snow-white-and-the-huntsman-2012","trailer":"http://youtube.com/watch?v=11Wn-_uyT48","runtime":127,"tagline":"","overview":"After the Evil Queen marries the King, she performs a violent coup in which the King is murdered and his daughter, Snow White, is taken captive. Almost a decade later, a grown Snow White is still in the clutches of the Queen. In order to obtain immortality, The Evil Queen needs the heart of Snow White. After Snow escapes the castle, the Queen sends the Huntsman to find her in the Dark Forest.","certification":"PG-13","imdb_id":"tt1735898","tmdb_id":"58595","poster":"http://trakt.us/images/posters_movies/180748.1.jpg","images":{"poster":"http://trakt.us/images/posters_movies/180748.1.jpg","fanart":"http://trakt.us/images/fanart_movies/180748.1.jpg"},"watchers":15,"ratings":{"percentage":68,"votes":105,"loved":71,"hated":34},"genres":["Adventure","Fantasy","Action","Drama"]}
```

I am trying to parse this and display it in my metro app but I cannot get it to work for hte life of me! I have tried many things such as this:

```
        string trendingURL = "http://Localhost/movies/trending.json/";


        MovieDetails newMovie = new MovieDetails();
        newMovie.title = "";
        newMovie.cover = "";

        //DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MovieDetails));

        //StreamReader sr = new Stream(trendingURL);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(trendingURL);
        var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MovieDetails));
        var collection = (MovieDetails)ser.ReadObject(str);
        var results = collection.title;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    string json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(trendingURL);
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    foreach (var item in obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", 
                    item.title, 
                    item.year, 
                    item.images.poster, 
                    item.ratings.votes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach but since these are dynamic, how would I retrieve such info to use?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library? According to Codeplex, it supports Windows 8 too, so you can do something like this:

```
var o = JObject.Parse(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
var newMovie = new MovieDetails();
newMovie.title = (string)o["title"];
newMovie.cover = (string)o["cover"];
```

Comment: -1 `JObject.Parse` will throw exception, because it is `JArray`

Answer (score 0):

Using speakeasy:

```
var client = new HttpClient("http://Localhost/");
var details = client.Get("movies/trending.json").OnOk().As<MovieDetails>();
```

you can install speakeasy using nuget.

Comment: Seems like this is not available for .net 4.5, will it support it soon?

Comment: It doesn't have to support .net 4.5, you can use .net 4.0 assemblies with .net 4.5 ones.